# Installation of Icinga on windows server

Tags: installation

I have two queries.

1. Can Icinga be installed on machine having windows 7?
   --> I am planing to use this as a server and installed the NSclient++ on another machine. In this I will have machine M1 as a server and machine M2 as client .
2. I could not find any document regarding the installation of Icinga on windows machine. Can someone provide me the document or the link to it.
   --> Documents related to installation of Icinga on linux is only mentioned.

Help needed ASAP

Answer (score 3):

Possibly using cygwin or some other *nix abstraction layer.
There is no "windows binary" of Icinga that I have heard of.

There is a windows port of Nagios https://www.itefix.no/i2/nagwin which might be a starting point depending on what you want to do...

But I would recommend install it on a Linux machine or inside a Linux virtual machine.

Comment: Thanx Mike, 
Could you please provide me with the detail steps for the installation of Icinga on Linux machine and also how should I proceed with the database.

Comment: The closet thing I guess is the getting started guide http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/ch02.html as well as the Quick Start guide http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/quickstart-icinga.html

Comment: I have installed icinga successfully as seen from the console window, but how do I verify that its working as when I type link http://localhost/icinga/  its shows me errors.